# Input range design in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I designed a `UserForm` in VBA that has a `RefEdit` control that helps users select input range. And for user's convenience, the initial default range in the `RefEdit` is set as `ActiveCell.CurrentRegion`. Normally, this works fine.

But there is a defect: if the user selects the whole columns as the address in the `RefEdit`, e.g., `Sheet1!$A:$C`, and the data block locates at `Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10`, my current program will throw an error message letting the user know that there is empty cell in the input range.

But the program should shrink back to `Sheet1!$A$1:$C$10` without sending an error message (You may check on `Data>Analysis>Data Analysis>Covariance` and select some whole columns, then you will understand what I am talking about). Of course, if input range is a block rather than whole columns, my program should not do any shrinkage but should go on the validation and any further computation on that block. How do I accomplish this?

The address is set in this way,

```
'   Select the current region
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
'   Initialize RefEdit control
    UF1.RE1.Text = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    UF1.RE1.SetFocus
    UF1.Show
```

Comment: Please share some code. There is no way to know what's going on otherwise.

Comment: Maybe set the area as the intersection of the input range and the used range, or check the size of the input range or whether it has blanks.

Comment: I just added the code used to initialize the address.@Kyle

Comment: Isn't `used range` a pretty unreliable concept in VBA?@SJR

Comment: I actually just wonder how Excel's Data Analysis able to handle data validation and whole column input both well.

Comment: But I will probably use `Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)` if I can't find a better answer@SJR

Comment: Yes `UsedRange` is not perfect, but why can't you just use the `CurrentRegion` - why does the user need to select a range at all?

Comment: You're right, but even the address in my `RefEdit` is correct, I may come across a user who still changes the input to whole columns after activating my `UserForm` for some reason we don't know. I (my company) just attempt to make this interface robust.@SJR

Comment: Is it possible to do the trick based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba? But I don't want to do this if the input range is not whole columns but normal block. Then I guess I need to do some string parsing on the `UF1.RE1.Text` to figure out if the input is whole columns, maybe?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even try to make this even more complicated by showing that the input can be something like `Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$C:$D` (this is possible if the computation is column-based), which would only make string parsing a big pain!!!

Comment: Maybe do a sense check on the count of the Ref Edit range.

Comment: Mabe check if the number of rows in the input range is `Rows.Count`, and shrink the array using the trick of [finding last used cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) I listed above? Is this what you are suggesting?@SJR

Comment: Exactly that. If your data are in one contiguous block you can just use `CurrentRegion`. If it could be anywhere, you can use Find to find the last used row and column and your last cell is the intersection of them.